# Tablesorter appears to be running twice for column selection

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablesorter

I've been using Mottie's excellent fork of Tablesorter for years.  I'm running across a problem I've never seen before, and I'm not sure where to start hunting for the issue.

All functions are working correctly, but when I click the **Column** button, it displays 'auto' twice, and pulls in things that are not columns.  In the image below, the items with red underlines are not part of the headers.  They are greyed out and can't be touched.  I have no idea where they are coming from.

[image]

The headers are derived from a dynamic entry set, pasted below.  Not sure this is relevant, but I'm posting the code in case it helps:

```
 <tr id="sort_data" data-col="{{$col}}">
        @foreach($atts as $cus_att)
           
            @if($cus_att->attribute->visible_in_list_view)
                <th class="center {{$cus_att->attribute->optional_in_list_view? 'columnSelector-false':''}}">
                   
                    {{$cus_att->attribute->name}}

                </th>
            @endif

        @endforeach
        <th class="center col-1" data-filter="false" data-sorter="false">{{__("Action")}}</th>
   </tr>
```

I don't know if I'm missing something obvious, but any thought as to where to start bug hunting would be most appreciated.

Thank you!

Rendered HTML:

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-bordered tablesorter tablesorter-blue tablesorterefb7ab942ea838columnselector hasResizable hasFilters hasStickyHeaders" data-sort-name="name" role="grid" aria-describedby="table1_pager_info">
<thead id="thead">

<tr id="sort_data" data-col="0" role="row" class="tablesorter-headerRow">
    <th class="center tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc" data-column="0" tabindex="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="table1" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: Ascending sort applied, activate to apply a descending sort"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
        Name
    </div></th>
    <th class="center tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-column="1" tabindex="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="table1" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;" aria-sort="none" aria-label="Owner: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
        Owner
    </div></th>
    <th class="center tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-column="2" tabindex="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="table1" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;" aria-sort="none" aria-label="Priority: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
        Priority
    </div></th>
    <th class="center tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-column="3" tabindex="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="table1" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;" aria-sort="none" aria-label="Data Location: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
        Data Location
    </div></th>
    <th class="center tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-column="4" tabindex="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="table1" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;" aria-sort="none" aria-label="Category: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
        Category
    </div></th>
    <th class="center columnSelector-false tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-column="5" tabindex="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="table1" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;" aria-sort="none" aria-label="Support: No sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
       Support
    </div></th>
    <th class="center col-1 tablesorter-header sorter-false tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-filter="false" data-sorter="false" data-column="6" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="true" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;" aria-sort="none" aria-label="Action: No sort applied, sorting is disabled"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Action</div></th>
</tr>


<tr role="row" class="tablesorter-filter-row tablesorter-ignoreRow"><td data-column="0" class="pointer center"><input type="search" placeholder="Search..." class="tablesorter-filter" data-column="0" data-lastsearchtime="1628907240814"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh reset" style="margin-top:4px;"></span></td><td data-column="1"><input type="search" placeholder="Search..." class="tablesorter-filter" data-column="1" data-lastsearchtime="1628907240814"></td><td data-column="2"><input type="search" placeholder="Search..." class="tablesorter-filter" data-column="2" data-lastsearchtime="1628907240814"></td><td data-column="3"><input type="search" placeholder="Search..." class="tablesorter-filter" data-column="3" data-lastsearchtime="1628907240814"></td><td data-column="4"><input type="search" placeholder="Search..." class="tablesorter-filter" data-column="4" data-lastsearchtime="1628907240814"></td><td data-column="5"><input type="search" placeholder="Search..." class="tablesorter-filter" data-column="5" data-lastsearchtime="1628907240814"></td><td data-column="6"><input type="search" placeholder="" class="tablesorter-filter disabled" data-column="6" disabled="" data-lastsearchtime="1628907240814"></td></tr></thead>

<tbody class="tbodyContent reorderDiv" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
```

TS Init

```
$(function() {

    var $table = $("table");

    var sortCol = $("#sort_data").data('col');

    $('button.columnSelectorButton').click(function(){
        $.tablesorter.storage( $table, 'tablesorter-columnSelector', [] );
        $.tablesorter.storage( $table, 'tablesorter-columnSelector-auto', {} );
        // reload the page
        document.location.reload();
    });

    /*** custom css only button popup ***/
    $table.tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        sortList: [[sortCol,0]],
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter',  'columnSelector', 'resizable', 'stickyHeaders'],
        widgetOptions : {
            resizable: true,
            resizable_addLastColumn: true,
            // Filters:
            filter_columnFilters: true,
            filter_placeholder: {search: 'Search...'},
            filter_saveFilters: false,
            filter_reset: '.reset',

            {{-- number or jquery selector targeting the position:fixed element -- how far from top should header
                sit, or create a class (like black_bar) that should alos be included in the sticky headaer --}}
            stickyHeaders_offset : 45,
            stickyHeaders : '.black_bar',

            {{-- target the column selector markup --}}
            columnSelector_container : $('#columnSelector'),
            {{-- column status, true = display, false = hide
                // disable = do not display on list --}}
            columnSelector_columns : {
                0: 'disable' /* set to disabled; not allowed to unselect it */
            },
            {{-- remember selected columns (requires $.tablesorter.storage) --}}
            columnSelector_saveColumns: true,

            {{-- container layout --}}
            columnSelector_layout : '<label><input type="checkbox">{name}</label>',
            {{-- data attribute containing column name to use in the selector container --}}
            columnSelector_name  : 'data-selector-name',

            {{-- Responsive Media Query settings
                 enable/disable mediaquery breakpoints --}}
            columnSelector_mediaquery: true,
            {{-- toggle checkbox name --}}
            columnSelector_mediaqueryName: 'Auto: ',
            {{-- breakpoints checkbox initial setting --}}
            columnSelector_mediaqueryState: true,
            {{-- hide columnSelector false columns while in auto mode --}}
            columnSelector_mediaqueryHidden: true,
            {{-- responsive table hides columns with priority 1-6 at these breakpoints
            // see http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/table-column-toggle/#Applyingapresetbreakpoint
            // *** set to false to disable *** --}}
            columnSelector_breakpoints : [ '20em', '30em', '40em', '50em', '60em', '70em' ],
            {{-- data attribute containing column priority
            // duplicates how jQuery mobile uses priorities:
            // http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/table-column-toggle/ --}}
            columnSelector_priority : 'data-priority',

            {{-- class name added to checked checkboxes - this fixes an issue with Chrome not updating FontAwesome
                 applied icons; use this class name (input.checked) instead of input:checked --}}
            columnSelector_cssChecked : 'checked'
        }
    })

    {{-- bind to pager events
         ********************* --}}
        .bind('pagerChange pagerComplete pagerInitialized pageMoved', function (e, c) {
            var msg = '"</span> event triggered, ' + (e.type === 'pagerChange' ? 'going to' : 'now on') +
                    ' page <span class="typ">' + (c.page + 1) + '/' + c.totalPages + '</span>';
            $('#display')
                    .append('<li><span class="str">"' + e.type + msg + '</li>')
                    .find('li:first').remove();
        })

    {{-- initialize the pager plugin
         **************************** --}}
        .tablesorterPager(pagerOptions);
```

TS pager options:

```
var pagerOptions = {

    // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
    container: $(".pager"),

    // use this url format "http:/mydatabase.com?page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:col}"
    ajaxUrl: null,

    // modify the url after all processing has been applied
    customAjaxUrl: function (table, url) {
        return url;
    },

    // ajax error callback from $.tablesorter.showError function
    // ajaxError: function( config, xhr, settings, exception ){ return exception; };
    // returning false will abort the error message
    ajaxError: null,

    // add more ajax settings here
    // see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings
    ajaxObject: {dataType: 'json'},

    // process ajax so that the data object is returned along with the total number of rows
    ajaxProcessing: null,

    // Set this option to false if your table data is preloaded into the table, but you are still using ajax
    processAjaxOnInit: true,

    // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}'
    // possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
    // also {page:input} & {startRow:input} will add a modifiable input in place of the value
    output: '{startRow:input} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',

    // apply disabled classname (cssDisabled option) to the pager arrows when the rows
    // are at either extreme is visible; default is true
    updateArrows: true,

    // starting page of the pager (zero based index)
    page: 0,

    // Number of visible rows
    size: 30,

    // Save pager page & size if the storage script is loaded (requires $.tablesorter.storage in jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js)
    savePages: true,

    // fix the column widths
    widthFixed: false,

    // Saves tablesorter paging to custom key if defined.
    // Key parameter name used by the $.tablesorter.storage function.
    // Useful if you have multiple tables defined
    storageKey: 'tablesorter-pager',

    // Reset pager to this page after filtering; set to desired page number (zero-based index),
    // or false to not change page at filter start
    pageReset: false,


    // if true, the table will remain the same height no matter how many records are displayed. The space is made up by an empty
    // table row set to a height to compensate; default is false
    fixedHeight: false,

    // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
    // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
    removeRows: false,

    // If true, child rows will be counted towards the pager set size
    countChildRows: false,

    // css class names of pager arrows
    cssNext: '.next', // next page arrow
    cssPrev: '.prev', // previous page arrow
    cssFirst: '.first', // go to first page arrow
    cssLast: '.last', // go to last page arrow
    cssGoto: '.gotoPage', // select dropdown to allow choosing a page

    cssPageDisplay: '.pagedisplay', // location of where the "output" is displayed
    cssPageSize: '.pagesize', // page size selector - select dropdown that sets the "size" option

    // class added to arrows when at the extremes (i.e. prev/first arrows are "disabled" when on the first page)
    cssDisabled: 'disabled', // Note there is no period "." in front of this class name
    cssErrorRow: 'tablesorter-errorRow' // ajax error information row

}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you share what the rendered HTML looks like? And the code you're using to initialize tablesorter.

Comment: Hi Mottie!  Thank you for taking a look.  I've used this init code over and over and it has worked great.  This project is BS 4 vs BS 3 for all other projects I've used it with, but I can't think of anything else glaring that is different.  I'm sure I've blanked somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I truly love this library, it is fantastic.  Thank you @Mottie.

I learned how to utilize the debug function and saw nearly 100 errors like the following:

```
Stopping initialization! No table, thead or tbody 
<table class="phpdebugbar-widgets-params" style="display: table; border: 0; width: 99%">
```

**Problem = conflict with phpDebugBar**, which I didn't realize, but is apparently trying to make its own table on the page and thus TS is looking to those headers too.

**To test (in Laravel or php app using a similar .env):**

I took the app out of dev mode by changing `.env` to show `APP_ENV=production` and `APP_DEBUG=false`.  This removes phpDebugBar from the page, and removed the issue along with the 100 debug notices.

**To fix:**

In the top line of the Tablesorter init file, I just changed the jQuery element from the generic 'table' to a specific id:

```
var $table = $("#table1");
```